# Set function as variable in function declaration

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

**I want to have function as variable in function declaration and than call that variable within declared function. How to do it in Swift?**

Pseudo code:

```
let something = 0

func one() {
    print("one")
}

// Definition
func two( funcVariable: Void, number: Int) {
   print("\(number)")
   funcVariable() // here I want to call variable function 
}

// Call
two(funcVariable: one(), number: somethhing)
```

**How to do it?**

Example code appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
let something = 0

func one() {
    print("one")
}

// Definition
func two(funcVariable: () -> Void, number: Int) {
   print("\(number)")
   funcVariable()
}

// Call
two(funcVariable: one, number: something)
```